# WAMP 5.5.30 installation Error in 32 bit system

Tags: php, wamp, wampserver, php-5.5

Downloaded wamp 5.5.30 from here :

http://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/files/WampServer%202/Wampserver%202.5/wampserver2.5-Apache-2.4.9-Mysql-5.6.17-php5.5.12-32b.exe/download

I found above link from official site of wamp server : http://www.wampserver.com/en/

At An Installation time, I am facing error described in below screenshot
[image]

I already installed Visual Studio 2012 : VC 11 vcredist_x64/86.exe
Visual Studio 2012 VC 11 vcredist_x64/86.exe : http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679

I am using windows 7,  32bit operating system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are more MSVC Runtimes required.

The WAMPServer install assumes you would be up to date with all these runtimes as lots of other software may also use these.

Make sure you have installed the redistributable packages VC9, VC10, VC11, VC13 and VC14

**VC9 Packages**

*For Windows 2000 Service Pack 4; Windows Server 2003; Windows Server 2008; Windows Vista; Windows XP, W7, W8*

[Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86) (32 bits)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5582)

[Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Redistributable Package (x64) (64bits)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2092)

---

**VC10 Packages**

*For Windows 7; Windows Server 2003; Windows Server 2008; Windows Server 2008 R2; Windows Vista; Windows XP*

[Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8328)

[Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package (x64)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13523)

---

**VC11 Packages Note:**

*VC11 is not supported by Windows XP
Windows 7 Service Pack 1; Windows 8; Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1; Windows Server 2012; Windows Vista Service Pack 2
The two files VSU4\vcredist_x86.exe and VSU4\vcredist_x64.exe to be download are on the same page:*

[Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 Update 4 (x86 and x64)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679)

---

**VC13 Packages**

*Windows 7 Service Pack 1; Windows 8; Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1; Windows Server 2012; Windows Vista Service Pack 2
The two files VSU4\vcredist_x86.exe and VSU4\vcredist_x64.exe to be download are on the same page:*

[Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784)

---

**VC14 Packages** *(Required for Apache 2.4.17 and PHP 7)*

*Windows 10, Windows 7 Service Pack 1, Windows 8, Windows 8.1, Windows Server 2003 Service Pack 2, Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1, Windows Server 2008 Service Pack 2, Windows Server 2012, Windows Vista Service Pack 2
The two files vcredist_x86.exe and vcredist_x64.exe to be download are on the same page:*

[Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2015 Update 1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49984)

**Also VERY BIG NOTE**

There is a newer version of WAMPServer out now WAMPServer3 available on sourceforge.

- They have improved the wampmanager to add lots of nice new features.
- There are ADDONS available for Apache2.4 and Apache2.2
- There are ADDONS available for various MYSQL Versions
- There are ADDONS available for PHP5.3, PHP5.4, PHP5.5, PHP5.6 and PHP7.0.0/1/2/3